# Tkinter button only responds visually after clicking out of and back into the window on Mac OSX

Tags: macos, tkinter, tkinter-button

I'm having some issues with very basic button functionality in Tkinter. Using the code below, I open a Tkinter window with a simple button:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

b = Button(root,text="Click Here")

b.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

When I click the button in the resulting window, I see no click animation (button should turn blue in Mac OSX)

[image]

However, I have found that if I click out of and back into the tk window, the buttons respond as expected.

[image]

I am using macOS Big Sur 11.3.

I'm hoping to find a way to have this second functionality when I first run the script. The button will still run commands, however it is not good design to have active buttons that don't visually respond to a click.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem did you find a walk around for this problem? Thanks

Comment: @user9468014 Never did find an answer sorry. Just been living with it for now. Might be worth reporting it as a bug if other people are having the same problem